# Major opcode of failed request: 1 (X_CreateWindow) with SFML on RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, opengl, raspberry-pi, sfml, glx

I'm trying to compile and run a simple SFML code on raspberry pi (raspbian os).
It does compile without any errors. When I run it,  I got following error.

```
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
    Major opcode of failed request: 1 (X_CreateWindow)
    Serial number of failed request: 34
    Current serial number in output stream: 36
```

I'm using SFML version 1.6 (sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev)

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    while (window.IsOpened())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.GetEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.Close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SFML 1.6 is **really** outdated... start by googling if someone actually succeeded in making SFML 2 run on pi. (I'm not sure that's the case.)

Comment: It worked after using SFML 2.0. Thanks